# Decide that database is Sybase or SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sybase

I would like to write an SQL script or query which can decide that the used database is SQL Server or Sybase.

How can I do that?

Comment: check for the existence of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`?

Comment: Pretty sure they both implement `select @@version`

Comment: thanks, this was the solution:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `select @@version`

---

In SQL Server it would present something like this:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64) 
    Jun 17 2011 00:54:03 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

---

In Sybase ASE it would present something like this:

```
Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.0.3/EBF 16736 ESD#2/P/Sun_svr4/OS 5.8/ase1503/2707/64-bit/FBO/Sun Jul 26 10:29:50 2009
```